# iteration over array for rendering dynamic data without div element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{ Object.keys(props.data).map((key, value) => {


  return(
         <div>
            <dt className="col-sm-3">{key}</dt>
            <dd className="col-sm-9">{props.data[key]}</dd>
         </div>
        )
  })}
```

The above code creating the following:

```
Key
Value
```

when hardcoding the above without the div wrapper element i'm getting:

```
Key           value
```

the full code chunk:

```
 <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-6">
                <div className="mb-5">
                    <h5 className="text-black">
                        <strong>{props.title}</strong>
                    </h5>
                    <dl className="row">
                        <dt className="col-sm-3">A</dt>
                        <dd className="col-sm-9">A</dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So my issue id the div wrapper element, is there a way to use map for rendering dynamic data without returning the div wrapper element?

Comment: You can use [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to wrap your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking semantically, it would be good idea to wrap with `dl`:

```
return(
  <dl>
    <dt className="col-sm-3">{key}</dt>
    <dd className="col-sm-9">{props.data[key]}</dd>
  </dl>
)
```

But looking at the code you're already defining `dl` and inside that you're using the component?

If you don't like the above solution only then you should use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html): (Use the above as far as possible)

```
return(
  <> {/* alias for React.Fragment */}
    <dt className="col-sm-3">{key}</dt>
    <dd className="col-sm-9">{props.data[key]}</dd>
  </>
)
```

---

Ah, you also need to provide `key` props:

```
<dl key={key}>
```

Or, using Fragment:

```
<React.Fragment key={key}>
```

The following is invalid use: (shorthand method doesn't support any props)

```
<key={key>
</>
```

Comment: still the same issue...

Comment: Updated my answer.